# Difference between wing chair and armchair

Tags: differences

What's the difference between wing chair and armchair?

I searched both with Google images and they looked almost the same -- chairs with sides where we can put our arms on them.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A wing chair has 'wings' up the side, originally intended to shield the sitter's torso and head from drafts. In these days of central heating the wings are just a 'design element'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've never head of a "wing chair".  I think that might be more technical term, that you would use in a furniture store, but nowhere else.

"Armchair" is much more common.

Comment: I agree. This is the first time that I have heard of it. It is not in the everyday language of, a lot of English speakers.

Comment: "I've never hear of" ... isn't an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: I think it helps a non-native speaker to know that even native speakers haven't heard of a term.  If the asker gets 10 Americans and British people saying they don't know the word, I think that's informative.  Certainly, it has to be more informative than dead silence.